# Finding duplicate contacts from table which are present in another array with the help of jQuery Rails 2.3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

```
Here is mY table  structure,



  <table class="editable">
    <tbody id="contacts">
    <tr class="no_items">
    <tr class="title_with_items">
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>e-mail</th>
    <th>Mobile</th>
    <th>Sender</th>
    <th>Sender e-mail</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="contact_container" style="display: none;">
    <tr class="contact_container">
    <td class="confirm">
    <td class="input">
    <input id="personal_event_event_contacts_attributes_1_first_name" type="text" value="test " size="12" name="personal_event[event_contacts_attributes][1][first_name]">
    </td>
    <td class="input">
    <td class="input">
    <td class="input">
    <td class="input">
    <td class="input">
    <td class="input">
    <td class="action">
    </tr>
    <tr class="contact_container">
    <td class="confirm">
    <td class="input">
    <input id="personal_event_event_contacts_attributes_1_first_name" type="text" value="test " size="12" name="personal_event[event_contacts_attributes][1][first_name]">
    </td>
    <td class="input">
    <td class="input">
    <td class="input">
    <td class="input">
    <td class="input">
    <td class="input">
    <td class="action">
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want to find duplicate contacts in the table, the contacts are being added by jQuery and not oin the database. I want to match records of this table with another array of attributes and find duplicates. This would be great if could be done with the help of Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Ive been searching for this one since long and finally found a way,

I wrapped the code in a function and found out the array of elements I wanted from the already present list and then matched it with the list I wanted.

```
function confirm_imported() {
    var getval_array = [];
    $('imported_contacts_table').select('[name="confirm"]').each(function(check, index)     {
      if (check.checked) {
         // Checking if the records already exist in the list.
        var totalvalues =
          $('contacts').select('tr.contact_container').map(function(value,i) {
           $val = $(value);
             var getvalues = $val.select('td.input').map(function(value, index) {
               return $(value).select(value)[0].value;
             });
             var spreadvalues = $(check).up('tr').select('td.input').map(function(cval,     cin){
                return $(cval).select(value)[0].value;
             });
           // Matching records with each other one from the spreadsheet to all.
           if (!(getvalues<spreadvalues || spreadvalues<getvalues)){
             getval_array.push(spreadvalues)
             return 1;
           }
           else {
           return 0;
           }
         });
         if (jQuery.inArray(1, totalvalues) === -1) {
          $('contacts').insert($(check).up('tr'));
        }
      }
     });
```